# NGINX: "upstream timed out" but request is automatically retried?

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I've a Kubernetes cluster in Azure which has a ingress-controller defined for a service named `test` using these settings:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  uid: 8f74ddb9-0e10-45f4-b0f7-283d59aac7e1
  resourceVersion: '354336339'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-26T07:01:10Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: chart
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.48.1.0
    helm.sh/chart: chart-1.0.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
```

The Pod is running a dotnet 6.0 WebApi.

When I do a GET request using Postman (or curl) to the `https://service.com/api/test/api/Test` endpoint, the request takes about 1 minute and 15 seconds.

The logging on the ingress controller shows the following:

```
2023/06/09 14:31:53 [error] 1047#1047: *227108924 upstream timed out 
 (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.2.128.35, 
 server: service.com, request: "GET /api/test/api/Test HTTP/1.1", 
 upstream: "http://10.2.128.161:80/api/Test", host: "service.com"


10.2.128.35 - - [09/Jun/2023:14:32:09 +0000] "GET /api/test/api/Test HTTP/1.1" 200 5043 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2" 1480 75.808 
  [default-test-service-80] [] 10.2.128.161:80, 10.2.128.161:80 0, 5043 60.009, 15.796 504, 200 2bc694b8bbe67a96abec5588fabc644b
```

From this logging, I conclude that the request times out (> 60.009 seconds), and in this case the dotnet WebApi returns a `ObjectResult` of type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails` with content-type `application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8` which should have some information on the exact cause of this timeout problem.

---

But this response is **not** returned to the caller (Postman/curl) and it seems that Ingress or Azure Loadbalancer does a a retry and this 2nd call succeeds within 15.796 seconds?

How to explain this?